# How to create shutdown sound, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, shutdown, 20.04

I have these two links that say how to create and link for shutdown sound. has not worked for me yet.  I have changed the file to K99 and k01.

method 1-  https://myubuntublog.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/shutdown-sound/#comments

method 2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248421/ubuntu-14-04-how-do-i-play-an-ogg-file-on-shutdown-with-a-script

Any help is appreciated.